# Need help in implementing a binary search in C

Tags: c, search, iteration, cs50

I am trying to write an iterative search in a C program.

The pseudo-code would look like this for it:

> while length of list > 0
>
> look at middle of list
>
> if number found, return true
>
> else if number is too high, only consider
>
> left half of list
>
> else if number is too low, only consider
>
> right half of list
>
> return false

I have already implemented a bubble sort (which I assume works).  Here is my code right now.  The search is currently linear.  I need to somehow change it to a binary search (I would prefer to do it iteratively instead of recursively).  I'm completely lost on how I should go about doing this though.  Can someone please help me?:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

/*
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */

bool 
search(int value, int array[], int n)
{

// TODO: re-implement as binary search
int min = 0;
int max = n;
int i;

i=(min+max)/2;
    if(array[i] == value)
        {
        return true;
        }
    else if(min>=max)
        {
        return 1;
        }
    else if(array[i] > value)
        {
        max = i-1;
        }    
    else if(array[i] < value)
        {
        min = i+1;
        }
    return false;
}



/*
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */

void 
sort(int values[], int n)
{
//set smade to false to start
//declares the_end as n-1
bool smade = false;
int the_end = n-1;

// TODO: implement an O(n^2) sort
while(the_end > 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < the_end; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        if (values[i] > values[i+1])
        {
            temp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[i+1];
            values[i+1] = temp;
            smade=true;
        }
    

}
if(! smade)
    {
    break;
    }
the_end--;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: you're mixing up sorting and searching. you've been tasked with  (binary) seach in an already sorted list. no need to sort it.

Comment: I understand.  I was the one who made that sorting code, I now need to search that sorted list using a binary search.

It took me a long time to even figure out how to do the bubble sort code.  I have no idea how to approach this search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just translate your pseudo-code into code. I'll give you some more refined pseudo-code:

1) Set minimum possible location for thing we're looking for (`min`) to zero.

2) Set maximum possible location for thing we're looking for (`max`) to the highest-possible location.

3) Compute a location `loc` as `(min+max)/2`.

4) Check if `loc` holds the object we're looking for. If so, stop, we found it.

5) Check if `min>=max`. If so, stop, it's not here.

5) If the object at `loc` is too high, set `max` to `loc-1`. (Because the maximum location at which it could be is one less than `loc`, since `loc` is too high.)

6) If the object at `loc` is too low, set `min` to `loc+1`. (Same logic, the other way around.)

7) Go to step 3.

Comment: This was REALLY helpful.  Is there any way I can show you what I wrote besides just editing my main post?  I hopefully did what you wrote out, but I'm still learning so I could be completely off (hence why I want you feedback on what I did if you don't mind).

Comment: You can update your question or you can post a link to a site like 'pastebin'.

Comment: I just updated the main one.  It seems to run fine (the top part).  The bottom part that I posted before this edit is full of errors though it seems (which has nothing to do with your thing, probably my mistakes).

Anyhow, do you think I did what you said correctly?  Also, do you have any idea why the sort part of this code is riddled with issues?

Comment: Edited it further to where it seems the sort (bottom) part works now.  There seems to be a problem with the top part though (search part).  It has something to do with me using 'i'.  I'm guess assuming I did everything else correctly (still not sure), that I need to put something else inside the array[].  Just wanted to update (updated in main post as well).

Comment: You have `array[i]` in a lot of places where you just want `i`.

Comment: I think I solved it.  The program (which works with another program) seems to now be doing the same outputs as the intructors program (don't have access to there code, but I can run it).

I'll include the final product in the main post if you have time to look at it :).

Comment: Ok, (had to edit it one more time) now it should be edited correctly.  Let me know what you think :).

Comment: Looks good. I'd just get rid of `if(array[i] < value)`, since it's the only remaining possibility. I sometimes do `else // if(array[i] < value)`, turning the 'if' into a comment but leaving it there to make clear what the case is.

Comment: oh, ok, that sounds good.  I, for whatever reason, always worry that I am including some other option for the last statement sometimes, even though I know that doesn't make sense (and know its bad form not to just say "else").  But your way sounds good. I'll do that from now on.  Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 1):

Soln;

```
unsigned char  search(int value, int array[], int n)
{
  int start = 0;
  int end = n;
  int mid;

  // We ll exit the while loop if we just started overlapping 
  while(start<=end)
  {
    // Calculating the new mid point
    // Can also be written as mid = (start + end)/2;
    mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    if(value == array[mid])
      return 1;

    // If value is less we search on the left side
    if(value < array[mid])
      end = mid - 1;
    else
      start = mid + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the algorithm there.  Just start with two index values -- low and high.  Set them initially to the first and last entries in the array.

Next pick an (integer) value midway between high and low.  Probe that array element.  If it's equal to the desired value, you're done.  If it's below/smaller/earlier than the desired value then set "low" to the probe element index +1.  If it's above/larger/later than the desired value, set "high" to the probe element index -1.  Then go back (in your while loop) and pick a new "midway" value.

If you get to where low > high (check in the while condition) then the value is not found.

(I'll add that the algorithm is basically simple, but can be frustratingly buggy if you don't think it out well and try to take some shortcuts.)

Comment: I tried it out with the above posters help.  It seems to still be wrong though.  In case David can't respond, do you know why the above isn't working?  I think it has to do something with putting i in things (and I shouldn't be).

Also, possibly I am way off from what I should be doing.

Comment: Critical step: *Then go back (in your while loop)*